# Фиксированый header на Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Здравсвуйте,зделал фикированый *header* на *jquery*.
Заметел что при прокрутки на начале страницы он неприятно дергается.
Подскажите пожалуйста,как это можно решить?

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > $('.top_header').outerHeight() )
 {

      $(' .right_nav .reservations a:last-child').hide(300);
    } else {
      $(' .right_nav .reservations a:last-child').show(200);
    }
  });
```

```css
header {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
}
header .top_header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: DINPro-Light, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.375em;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  margin: 0;
}
header .top_header .left_nav {
  float: left;
}
header .top_header .left_nav .menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: -6px;
  max-width: 60px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}
header .top_header .left_nav .menu img {
  padding: 0 8px;
  width: 55px;
}
header .top_header .left_nav .tel {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 16px;
}
header .top_header .right_nav {
  float: right;
}
header .top_header .right_nav .reservations {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #cba673;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
header .top_header .right_nav .reservations img {
  width: 27px;
}
header .top_header .right_nav .language {
  margin-left: -6px;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 0 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="top_header">
    <div class="left_nav">
      <div class="menu">
        |||
      </div>
      <div class="tel">
        +38 097 060 05 57
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_nav">
      <div class="reservations">
        <a href="#">[|||]</a>
        <a href="#">Забронировать</a>
      </div>
      <div class="language">
        Eng
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

[Пример на codepen](http://codepen.io/jSas/pen/GrvoJE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.reservations a {
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > $('.top_header').outerHeight() )
 {

      $(' .right_nav .reservations a:last-child').hide(300);
    } else {
      $(' .right_nav .reservations a:last-child').show(200);
    }
  });
```

```css
header {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
}
header .top_header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: DINPro-Light, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.375em;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  margin: 0;
}
header .top_header .left_nav {
  float: left;
}
header .top_header .left_nav .menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: -6px;
  max-width: 60px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}
header .top_header .left_nav .menu img {
  padding: 0 8px;
  width: 55px;
}
header .top_header .left_nav .tel {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 16px;
}
header .top_header .right_nav {
  float: right;
}
header .top_header .right_nav .reservations {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #cba673;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
header .top_header .right_nav .reservations img {
  width: 27px;
}
header .top_header .right_nav .language {
  margin-left: -6px;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 0 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}
.reservations a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="top_header">
    <div class="left_nav">
      <div class="menu">
        |||
      </div>
      <div class="tel">
        +38 097 060 05 57
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_nav">
      <div class="reservations">
        <a href="#">[|||]</a>
        <a href="#">Забронировать</a>
      </div>
      <div class="language">
        Eng
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Да. так проще :)

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в том, что когда блок `a` уменьшается в размерах, то текст не влазит и поднимается вверх. Вам нужно указать для блока `.reservations`, что бы все элементы в нём всегда стояли в строчку и не вылазили. Для этого можно использовать `flexbox`. В вашем случае заменить `display: inline-block` на `display: inline-flex`:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > $('.top_header').outerHeight() && $(window).width() > 200 /* Настоящий размер: 768 */) {

      $(' .right_nav .reservations a:last-child').hide(300);
    } else {
      $(' .right_nav .reservations a:last-child').show(200);
    }
  });
```

```css
header {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
}
header .top_header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: DINPro-Light, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.375em;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  margin: 0;
}
header .top_header .left_nav {
  float: left;
}
header .top_header .left_nav .menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: -6px;
  max-width: 60px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}
header .top_header .left_nav .menu img {
  padding: 0 8px;
  width: 55px;
}
header .top_header .left_nav .tel {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 16px;
}
header .top_header .right_nav {
  float: right;
}
header .top_header .right_nav .reservations {
  display: inline-flex; /* Эта строчка */
  background-color: #cba673;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
header .top_header .right_nav .reservations img {
  width: 27px;
}
header .top_header .right_nav .language {
  margin-left: -6px;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 0 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="top_header">
    <div class="left_nav">
      <div class="menu">
        |||
      </div>
      <div class="tel">
        +38 097 060 05 57
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_nav">
      <div class="reservations">
        <a href="#">[|||]</a>
        <a href="#">Забронировать</a>
      </div>
      <div class="language">
        Eng
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

P.S. Не используйте `inline-*`. Это не кроссбраузерное значение. Лучше самому указать ширину блока.